# Perform validation of returned values of Interface

Tags: java, interface

I've a base class ClassA which is:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public ClassA {
   private String version;
}
```

Few classes extend classA
such as

```
@Data
public class B extends classA {
   private String a;
   private String b;
}
```

I've an interface which has the following method:

```
<T extends ClassA> T read(SomeOtherObject object, Class<T> clazz);
```

Now in the implementation of the interface

```
<T extends ClassA> T read(SomeOtherObject object, Class<T> clazz) {
   T obj = callSomeMethod(); //Call SomeMethod will return an object which fills in properties of T and doesn't know how to set value of version
   obj.setVersion("123");
   return obj;
}
```

How do I ensure that every implementation of this interface sets a non empty value of version in ClassA ?

Comment: You want to make sure `version` is set in every implementation?

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes thats right. Updated question

Comment: And what is supposed to happen when an implementation doesn't?

Comment: @akuzminykh throw an exception

Comment: Then I don't think there is any (good) alternative to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61672947/12323248).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that using interfaces. You can achieve something close by using an abstract class instead of the interface

```
abstract class TheClass {
    public final <T extends ClassA> T read(SomeOtherObject object, Class<T> clazz) {
        T actual = this.doRead(object, clazz);
        if(null == actual.getVersion() || actual.getVersion().trim().isEmpty())
            throw SomeException();
    }

    protected abstract <T extends ClassA> T doRead(SomeOtherObject object, Class<T> clazz);
}
```

Or by making `ClassA` itself reject empty `version` values:

```
@Getter
public ClassA {
   private String version;

   public void setVersion(String v) {
       if(null == v || v.trim().isEmpty()) throw SomeException();
       this.version = v;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Only downside with approach 2 is that, the interface implementation can avoid calling the setter. With approach 1 using abstract class, it is guaranteed that validation will occur